# How to check if an Arraylist index is empty

Tags: java, arraylist, null, is-empty

I have a question asking to read indexes and check if its empty and if it is and its at a position greater than or equal to 67(starting from 0), I must print out the element located at index i-67. The problem I'm having I believe is checking if an index contains anything

```
  for(int i = 0; i <= s.size()-1; i++){
    if(s.get(i) == null && i >= 67)
      w.println(s.get(i-67));
  }
```

I read elsewhere that maybe a hashtable would be better for doing this but I for the life of me can't understand why.

Comment: runtime error, compiler error, wrong data output, please specify.

Comment: `i <= s.size()-1;`  really?

Comment: Sorry, wrong data output was my issue, as it would never recognize if an index was empty.

@FredK yes what about it?

Anyways I found a solution to my question, apparently I was using the wrong data structure for the problem. Also if anyone cares to know the reason it wouldn't pick up was because Strings are not a primitive data type so you'd need to do 
    if(s.get(i).equals(null))
to get the correct result! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Using `if(s.get(i) == null)` doesn't work, and the method `get()` throws an exception instead of returning null.

You need to catch the exception, use this:

```
try {
    s.get(i);
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    s.add(i, new Object());//Add something to fill this position.
}
```

If the Arraylist in the `i` position is null (empty), the code catch the exception and you can add something to fill that position. You didn't specify what type is your Arraylist.